# How can I copy files from one server to another using scp or sftp in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, scp, sftp

I am currently creating a script where I want to copy files from one server to another using either `scp` or `sftp`; the thing I'm confused with is authentication.

If I use `scp` then how will I give the password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this sort of automated use, you shouldn't be using password authentication, you should be using key-based authentication.  With key-based, the connection will happen without the need for any password prompting.

You need to generate a key pair on the side where you're using the SSH client, and then copy your public key over to the SSH server.  You'll find endless pages on how to make that happen, but here's one:

https://www.linode.com/docs/security/authentication/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh/

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my doubt.

Comment: And keys are more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh keys for more security

Or you can install sshpass and do something as:

`sshpass -p "password" scp file.txt user@machine:/path`